# Switch Off Universal Navigation in Google Marketplace Application

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a Marketplace app in the new Marketplace that we do not want the universal navigation extension to be visible for.

In the setup you can uncheck "Enable Universal Navigation extension".  It then forces you to "Enable Drive extension".

we don't want either of these options.  We only want API access, which is granted by installing the app from the marketplace.

Does anybody know the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a workaround to solve this problem.

I enabled a "Drive Extension" but configured the Drive extension so that it never shows up in Drive by setting a "Default File Extension" that will never occur - eg "neveroccur".

Using this approach there is no universal navigation and my app can access the APIs for the whole organization.  Users cannot see a drive extension as it never activates because the file type does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that there is any solution, either one is required.
Simply point the universal navigation to any HTML page with general info or your company website, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - this is what we have currently done - we have some large customers with say 100,000 Google Apps users and only say 1000 use our app.  This is an issue for them as they do not want to put the users using our app in an "Organizational Unit" so can't be segmented off.

Comment: If this is not a public app but developed for a customer, then you can setup visibility for the application to only a specific google group in the chrome webstore. This way only the specified users can see the app, without modifying your OUs.